Number of images formed by a convex lens
I came across a thought and (literally) am very vexed with it. My recreation of it is :-

I know I am bad at drawing so forgive that. So, what I thought is that if we have a lens kept in vacuum, which has two parts divided by the principle axis, the upper having a refractive index of $\mu  1 $ and the lower having a refractive index of $\mu  2 $,, then how many images would be formed?
As this is a question coming directly out of my mind, I want all possible solutions. In simpler words, there is no guarantee that the medium surrounding the lens is optically rarer, but consider it homogeneous.
My guess was 4 images, but I am not sure.
My reasoning diagrams are:-
Firstly,

Secondly,

Thirdly,

Lastly,

If there is any doubt about my reasoning and why I had drawn like this, feel free to comment. In general, I had considered the first medium to be optically rarer than the second.
I would be grateful to the helpers. Thanks in advance.
Edit:- To the answerers, the main focus is the number pf images. The answers having diagrams have forgotten about the refraction at the media separating the two lenses. They just gave diagrams, where the ray passed undeviated through the optical center.

The answer to your question is possibly answered here - Why do we draw two rays from a same point on an object during image formation?

I found a fourth real image that is formed by total internal reflection off the interface boundary if u1>u2. See my updated answer.

You are making the assumption that wherever two rays intersect, an image is formed. If you look at the diagram below, you will see dozens of intersections of two rays, even between the red and blue rays (the black dots) but to make a significant detection at the focal plane, there should be a convergence of multitudes of rays at a point, such as where the primary images are ($P_1$ and $P_2$). Ordinarily, when we draw an optical diagram, focal points are shown as a convergence of two or maybe three rays as a convenience, but it is understood they represent a bundle of thousands or even millions of rays. The diagram below is for the case of $u_1<u_2$. The case of $u_1>u_2$ (where total internal reflection is significant) is illustrated further down.

In a camera, the image CCD is divided into pixel areas and if thousands of photons converge on a single pixel, it will register as a bright spot, but if only a few photons converge on that area, it will barely register as a bright spot. If the rays are evenly emitted in all directions from the source, the number of rays that converge on a single point gives a good indication of the relative brightness at that point.

In your fourth image, you have correctly drawn the ray passing through the centre and the interface of the two mediums as diverging away from the optical axis. When combined with the other rays passing through that middle region, the rays do not all cleanly converge to a single point. They produce what is known as a 'circle of confusion', which is seen on a photograph as an out-of-focus blurry point ($P_3$). It can be seen in the diagram that only about $10\%$ of the rays pass through the interface, dividing the two halves of the lens, so any image formed by these rays will be much dimmer than the images formed at the other two points.

What about the effects of total internal reflection (either within one
lens or where the two lenses meet)? – TLDR

I decided to do a more in-depth investigation of this aspect. It turns out that if the refractive index of the top lens is greater than that of the lower lens, the rays can experience total internal reflection at certain angles, and these reflected rays converge to a surprisingly good focus and produce a 4th real image as per the ray tracing diagram below. I used $u_1 = 2.4$ and $u_2 = 2.3$ for the simulation. Some of the rays can pass through the interface even when $u_1>u_2$ if the angle is right. Note in the above diagram that one of the green rays on the far right manages to pass through the interface. This means a total of up to $4$ significant real images can be formed when $u_1>u_2$. This 4th image is effectively a reflection of the $P_2$ image, so it is at the same distance from the lens and the same height but inverted.

What is the minimum number of rays (photons) that need to hit the sensor of a camera to form an image? The most modern sensitive cameras, such as those used in a space telescope, can register even a single photon hitting a pixel. This means even a single ray intersecting the image plane can register as an activated pixel. However, the pixels that are activated by one or two photons will be very faint compared to pixels where thousands or millions of photons are converging on a single pixel. However, it is only fair to point out that even with the best cameras, random thermal noise can cause pixels to register faint false positives, and the faint images formed from single or double rays converging on a point would probably be very difficult to separate from background thermal noise.
Conclusion: Up to $4$ real images can be formed if $u_1>u_2$, although the third image formed by rays that pass through the middle interface will be a bit fuzzy. The third and fourth images would generally be much fainter than the first two images because the interface intercepts fewer rays from the source. For $u_1<u_2$, there would be $3$ real images as in the first diagram.

Yh, seems satisfactory.

Can, the 3rd be virtual?

@Ritzthephysibeast Having done some further calculations and geometry i have concluded that the 3rd image can be real but, but not very well focused and much fainter than the first two images. I have edited my answer with this update and updated the diagram that is now much closer to reality but still involves some approximations. An exact solution would require a sophisticated numerical ray tracing simulation.

What about the effects of total internal reflection (either within one lens or where the two lenses meet)?

The internally reflected rays diverge off in multiple directions and are sometimes reflected more than once. Some of these rays might form images, but they are are a small subsection of the total rays and so any images they form will be faint. I did mention this somewhere in the middle of the answer. There is some internal reflection at the interface between the two lens halves and mostly they just diminishes the brightness of the third image that is formed by the rays that do pass through the interface, even further.

Seems that my guess was correct then. Though not in the way I thought

@KDP Will P4 always be a reflection of P2?

Yes, I think P4 will always be a reflection of P2 when P4 forms. Sometimes P4 will not form, if the source is far from the optical axis, so that the angle of incidence is smaller and the rays pass through the central interface. In that case they form a blurry image similar to to P3.. Sometimes, depending on the width of the interface and the angles of incidence both things will happen. Some will be reflected and form P4 and some will pass through on the right side of the interface and form a version of P3, giving a total of 4 images in very specific circumstances.

You can imagine we have a special optical material for the bottom half of the lens and that we can electronically adjust the refractive index of the bottom half. If initially we set the refractive index of the lower half equal to that of the upper half, we will have a complete normal lens with a focus only at P2. If we now reduce  the refractive index of the lower half, some of the rays that were originally converging on P2 start to form a new  P3 image that moves away from P2. If we reduce the refractive index further, the rays that would have gone to P2 are reflected to P4.

Note that if all the lens in made with material with refractive index equal to u1, all the rays that converge on P2 only pass through material that has a refractive index of u1. It can be seen in the diagram that the reflected rays that form P4 also only pass through material that has refractive index of u1. The geometry of the upper half and lower half are the same so the geometry is symmetrical, so P4 will always be a reflection of P2.

You can also note that I did not include the very top of the lens in the red region that depicts the red rays that pass through the upper half. Total internal reflection also occurs there and numerous . and they will form minor images elsewhere. Real lenses are not as perfect as the simplified diagrams that are normally used suggest. There are numerous sub images all over the place. For a typical spherical lens the convergence to a focal point is not as clean cut as the diagrams suggest. Nearly all formulas for focal distance are approximations and averages.

@KDP Yes that's a helpful insight. Also, it would be great if we could have an electronic machine like that (I don't think any exist)

The liquid crystal layer in a LCD change its optical properties when a voltage is applied. That is how they work. Specifically they change the polarisation of the light passing through. There may be similar materials that alter refractive index when voltage is applied but I am not certain. There was a recent question which mentioned a material in a Mach Zehnder interferometer experiment, that changed and allowed light to pass or reflect when pumped with a pulse laser, but I cannot find it at the moment. Rapid advances are being made in optically adaptive materials.

A very primitive version would be to have a hollow lens filled with water and pump a liquid with a different refractive index into the cavity.

Apparently a gold nanofilm can change its refractive index when a voltage is applied https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-024-50665-7

Also https://www.rp-photonics.com/pockels_effect.html

You have a couple misconceptions.
You don't see an object. You see light that bounced off the object.
A lens takes light from an object and makes an image, which is light that looks like it bounced off an object.
Light bounces off each point of an object. That light goes through a lens and forms a point in the image. Many rays come from each object point. They all are focused to the same image point.
If you want to find out where the image point is, you can follow two rays through the lens and see where they cross.
So the lines on the left should be rays that leave the same point.

You could draw a whole fan of rays leaving a point. Those that went through the upper lens would get focused to an image point. Those that went through the lower lens would get focused to a different image point. So there are two images.

Sad, to say, but didn't clear my confusion.

From Lensmaker's formula for same lens curvatures
$$\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}=\mu_1f_1= \mu_2f_2$$
$$\text{ red}f_1>\text{ blue}f_2,\mu_1<\mu_2 $$
There are two lenses or lens halves, so two separate refraction image formations by standard ray tracing drawing in this particular case of same object distance:


To determine the number of images, you need to trace all possible families of qualitatively distinct paths that light rays might (generically) take, and for each generic family determine if a convergent real or virtual image is formed.
Three families of paths are immediately clear: rays that pass through either the upper lens or the lower lens, but not both, and rays that are incident on both the upper and the lower parts of the (joint) lens.  From experience, or from the lens equation, we know that the upper and lower paths will be associated with a single image.  The middle path is slightly less straightforward, however.
To dissect it, let's assume (without loss of generality) that the light source of interest is in the upper region, so its parallel ray intersects the upper lens, and that the index of refraction in the upper lens is larger than that in the lower lens (after exploring this case we will need to consider what happens when the lower index of refraction is larger than the upper index.)
Consider all light rays emanating from the source toward the lens, and label each by its incident polar angle.  In general, there is some angular interval $[\theta_{min}, \theta_{max}]$ for which the light rays will pass through both lenses and outside of which light rays pass through a single lens (either the top or the bottom.) The termini of this interval will be associated with points/curves where the top lens meets the bottom one, on the side facing the source or away from it. Consider light rays near the point facing the source: if $n_2 < n_1$, several possibilities exist for how outgoing light rays enter the top lens and then meet with the second lens.  Assuming $n_0 < n_1$, all outgoing light rays incident on the top lens will enter it at a 'steeper' angle relative to the normal, but a 'shallower' angle relative to the line/surface separating the two lenses. If this angle is shallow enough, the light rays will undergo total internal reflection, bounce off the top of the lower lens without entering it, and exit the upper lens on the far side (where they will tend to concentrate as if they had passed through a single lens from a vertically inverted source).  If this happens for all light in a neighborhood of the near point (where the two lenses meet), the geometry is such that it will also happen for all light rays emitted between $\theta_{min}$ and $\theta_{max}$.  In this case, three images are formed.
Similarly, if the incident angle on the second lens on the far side of the (joint) lens is less than the critical angle for the two media, light at this point will pass through both lenses over the entire $[\theta_{min}, \theta_{max}]$ interval without undergoing internal reflection. In this case, there are also three images, one of which will appear to be somewhat distorted vertically (stretched or flattened, depending on the steepness of the incident angle, but typically flattened somewhat.)
Between these two limiting cases (which depend on the geometry of the source relative to the lens), there will exist a critical angle $\theta^*$ in $[\theta_{min}, \theta_{max}]$ separating rays that undergo internal reflection from those that pass through both lenses without internal reflection, resulting in four images in total (two of which will be related by reflection.)
Now let's consider the case where $n_1 < n_2$.  Under these conditions, there will be no internal reflection between the top and bottom lens, but there might be internal reflection in the bottom lens at the outer surface (i.e. the surface exposed to air.)  Similar boundary cases apply under these conditions, with a critical (normal, incident) angle $\theta^*$ above which rays will tend to undergo internal reflection in the lower lens and below which they will tend to pass through without internal reflection.  In the thin lens approximation the number of internal reflections is essentially infinite (even just above the cutoff), but in general the number of reflections will depend on the size of the lens, the size and distance to the ray source, and will tend to vary (over a 'macroscopically negligible' but possibly 'microscopically appreciable' range) with the geometry of the setup. When the lens width is non-negligible compared to the lens diameter, the number of internal reflections will be 'small' (i.e. not an absurdly large number), and again will depend on the geometry of the problem. Hence, there will be additional critical angles $\theta^{(n)}$ where the number of internal reflections changes. Moreover, in the thick-lens case (or 'small, nearby source' limit), it is possible for several of these critical angles to fall within $[\theta_{min}, \theta_{max}]$ simultaneously, thus creating additional images (possibly a macroscopic number, depending on how close the source is to lens as well as its size.)

Well, so I can expect 4 images? (Some rays must be at $\theta *$)And of course, an infinite microscopic images. But can i expect more macroscopic images?

It helped, really, though

Sorry, my answer might have been somewhat misleading: the number of images depends on the location of the source/emitter and the shape of the lens.  If the lens is very thin relative to its diameter, for example, you would expect most of the internally reflected light to continue to reflect until it reached the edge (and an extra image would only appear under very special conditions.)

Yh, that's what I had considered in the first place.

I just make the picture to the answer of mmesser.
You have the picture to focus F,F_1 at H all light in the green  triangle gets collected there, the light going through the  upper half part (with F',F'1) is spread out wide at point H so just makes the picture a little less prominent. The same at point K the picture of the upper half.
since you did not put in the foci I can't correct your picture, your picture three is wrong since you use the same focus for both halfs. 

I didn't use the same focus. The fact is I didn't differentiate by drawing the focus. But the deviation is not same.

In the picture 3 you used the same focus for upper an lower half, so picture 3 does not exist. All the rays through the upper part meet at a different point than the once through the lower part. What you mean with "But the deviation is not same." I don't understand

That's an optical illusion cuz my bad drawing, but my idea is well understood, ig. Coz, I wanted to just show that the rays meet.

The two rays you drew may meet, but what of the rest of rays through upper and lower part? Did you understand my drawings? Even in my drawing, you find rays going through the different parts meeting, but at very different points, 2 rays meeting don't make a picture, all the rays from a point have to meet.

No, but technically speaking, if the green lines intersect the red ones, an image should be formed. For a single point to form an image 2 rays are enough. You can check the reference I gave to ayesha J

"For a single point to form an image 2 rays are enough" is very wrong! two rays are often used to construct an image but it is assumed (without explicitly saying) that ALL the rays in between go through the same point,

Yes, I get that but is it true that that point has only 2 rays intersecting. This is a very crucial thing, because the refraction in lens in not that simple. Coz, you said it right, that "it is assumed... the same point". However, there is no guarantee that the rays in between don't meet there.

In simpler words, the thing that infinite rays from an object point need to meet at an image point is wrong. If a couple of rays meet, we can assume about rays in between.

So first of all, all the four diagrams you have made are correct.
For figure 1 and 2 all the other infinite rays (passing through either upper or lower part of lens only) that you could possibly make from the tip of object will ultimately focus on the tip of their respective image diagrams.
But for figure 3 and 4, the rays which you have shown from the tip of object are the only rays that intersect at that particular tip of image say $P_1$. That in itself is a single point. Now draw two more rays from the tip of object and deviate them by a very small bit such that they satisfy the initial condition that one ray passes from upper part of the mixed lens and the other passes through the lower part of the mixed lens, you will observe that it will not pass through $P_1$ now but instead from some other point $P_2$. Similarly, the image of 'just the tip of object (say $O$)' formed by all the varying rays, one passing through upper portion and the other passing through lower portion, do not coincide, but are scattered in space. So imagine seeing the image of just point $O$ : scattered points even smaller than what is called 'a point'; you can't see it all together. So how will you be able to form an object out of it at all $-$ that is something to ponder about.
In conclusion, in space around us, there are infinite rays which intersect another set of infinite rays, but all of them do not form entities which we can see because they are still points. We can only see see those points which are intersection of atleast infinite points (well... too deep I guess :/, but...), hope this helps.
Therefore rays like those in figure 3 and 4 are definitely formed, but they do not contribute in a proper image formation, so only two image (one each from figure 1 and 2) will be formed.
Kindly comment for further clarification.

https://byjus.com/question-answer/minimum-number-of-rays-required-to-form-an-image-of-an-object-using-a-convex/

See this reference.

The reference says that "minimum two rays are required to form an image of an object using a convex lens", does not necessarily mean two rays of an object passing through a convex lens must always form an image.

By your reference, I presume you know HCV and hindi, so this might be helpful : https://youtu.be/wWVE1ALlbYY?si=IhhcNTzlxgiQOqyB from 7:45. Notice how he emphasizes that all rays (the other infinite ones also) meet there only that is why two is sufficient.

What is HCV? Can you please tell.

Kindly search for H.C. Verma

Why did you never comment on my picture in the answer, what did you not understand about it?

@trula Your pic gives me a decent reason to believe that there would be 2 images. However, the many possible refractions which may take place, also align in some different planes.

What places can you find, so that all rays in a bundel meet at one point, there are not many possible refractions, only the ones in the upper part and lower part. Just indicate the focus for the uper and lower part and try to construct, what you claim is possible.

The rule in optics in that any finite section of a lens will act as a full lens. In principle, this can be any segment (the only catch is that the speed of each segment will be reduced proportionally with its total area, i.e. the image will be proportionally dimmer). In your case, you have a total of two lens segments, therefore you will have two images.

That's the easy conclusion. I wanted deeper insight, so I declared a bounty.

Precisely. Simple observations need proportionally simple explanations. If you're curious why any lens segment acts as a full lens, the answer is beyond this question. But you can always post a separate question on that and I can answer it there. I don't ask for a bounty.
